# Ladder operator identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Define $n=(x + iy)/\sqrt{2}L$ and $\overline n=(x - iy)/\sqrt{2}L$.

Also, $\partial_n$ = $L(\partial_x - i \partial_y)/\sqrt{2}$  and  $\partial_\overline n$ = $L(\partial_x + i \partial_y)/\sqrt{2}$.

with $\partial_n=\partial/\partial n$, $\partial_x=\partial/\partial x$, $\partial_y=\partial/\partial y$, and L being the magnetic length.

Show that $a=\frac 12 \overline n +\partial_n$ and $a^+=\frac 12 n -\partial_\overline n$

$a$ and $a^+$ are the lowering and raising operators of quantum mechanics.

Is showing that the commutator of $a$ and $a^+$ enough? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should prove that if $a$ and $\frac{1}{2}\bar{n}+\partial_n$ act on a ket vector (or simply, wave function), we have the same results. In other words, those two operator should have the same eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.

Comment: @LêDũng Thanks for that info, It helped a lot. I have another question, given the information above how can I show that H=ħω(a†a+ 1/2) with ω being the cyclotron frequency? I have tried to find x,y,∂x,∂y in terms of n,ñ,∂n,∂ñ and substitute to the Hamiltonian but ended up getting only half the terms needed to prove it. Is my method correct?

Comment: To prove $H=\hbar(a^{\dagger}a+1/2)$, one should know the orgininal form of Hamiltonian. Is it the Hamiltonian for quantum harmonic oscillator?